# Google Spreadsheets - work together with same sheet but different filtering for each user

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to work on a shared Google Spreadsheet workbook.
The problem is that on every filter I do on my side, my friends' book is also been filtered.

I would like to know if there is any possibillity we can work together, but with diffrence "filtering" for the same book.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Use the new spreadsheet feature "Filter Views" your filter parameters can be saved, and they do not automatically apply to other sheet users as is explained in this excerpt from Google sheets help...

Filters vs. Filter Views

Adding a filter will change the view for anyone viewing the spreadsheet, while filter views need to be explicitly turned on by each person. Each person in a spreadsheet could be viewing a different filter view at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

In this case your friend does not actually have his or her own copy, it is shared, with you as the owner.  If your friend creates a copy of it to work with, *then* you can each make changes to your own documents without affecting the other.

Comment: thank you for the reply. We have a database we would like to work on it together - I am working to a certin filter and he on other one.

In this case - how can we edit together the DB?